# exclude time from other table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two tables: Outages and PlannedMaintance. I have to fetch the outages records which lies under specific date time range and if this time comes under PlannedMaintance, skip these record. for ex. if there are 10 records coming between `1 may 2019 12:00 AM` to `09 May 2019 11:59 PM` and plannedDowntime Tables has record for StartDownTime is `3 May 2019 10:35 AM` and EndDownTime is `3 may 2019 11:00 AM`. during this period, there are 3 records in outages, we need to skip these and output list should have 7 records.

I don't want to loop on the records. The will be records hundreds of thousands, it may chock the website.

Here is table structures:

Outage

[image: Outage table]

PlannedDownTime

[image: PlannedDownTime Table]

Entity Framework Query:

```
  var netwrokErrorsQuery = db.Outages.Where(_ => _.OutageType == "Network" && _.OutageStart >= startDate && _.OutageEnd <= endDate).ToList().Where(_=>_.OutageStart.Hour<2 && _.OutageStart.Hour > 5 || _.OutageEnd.Value.Hour < 2 && _.OutageEnd.Value.Hour > 5).ToList();
        var softwareErrorsQuery = db.Outages.Where(_ => _.OutageType == "Software" && _.OutageStart >= startDate && _.OutageEnd <= endDate).ToList().Where(_ => _.OutageStart.Hour < 2 && _.OutageStart.Hour > 5 || _.OutageEnd.Value.Hour < 2 && _.OutageEnd.Value.Hour > 5).ToList();
        var hardwareErrorsQuery = db.Outages.Where(_ => _.OutageType == "Hardware" && _.OutageStart >= startDate && _.OutageEnd <= endDate).ToList().Where(_ => _.OutageStart.Hour < 2 && _.OutageStart.Hour > 5 || _.OutageEnd.Value.Hour < 2 && _.OutageEnd.Value.Hour > 5).ToList();
```

i am not able to get any way any idea how i can do it

Comment: Is there has any relation between these table?

Comment: Is db.Outages.Where(_ => _.OutageType == "Network" && _.OutageStart >= startDate && _.OutageEnd <= endDate && !db.PlannedMaintenances.Any(x=>x.StartDate<=_.OutageStart && x.EndDate>=_.OutageEnd)) what you want? Notice however that you do quite a bit of computation in memory, as the .ToList() call in each of these statements will cause the preceding query to be compiled and executed against the database.

Comment: @ColonelSoftware, no relation

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var records = db.Outages
           .Join(db.PlannedDownTime,
                 o => o.ReaderId,
                 p => p.ReaderId,
                 (o, p) => new {
                     OutageStart = o.OutageStart,
                     OutageEnd = o.OutageEnd,
                     DowntimeStart = p.DowntimeStart,
                     DowntimeEnd = p.DowntimeEnd
                 }
                 ).Where(r=>r.OutageStart >= START_TIME)
                 .Where(r=>r.OutageEnd <= END_TIME)
                 .Where(r=>(r.DowntimeStart < START_TIME && r.DowntimeEnd < START_TIME ) || (r.DowntimeStart > END_TIME && r.DowntimeEnd > END_TIME ))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: this will only get the outages for those readers that also have a planned downtime.

Comment: right, as well as will not fetched the record if OutageStart is greater than Start_Time and OutageEnd is greate than End_Time. Need to have between for dates